# Web Scraping: Problems with the HTML source code

Tags: html, css

I try to web scrape data from this site: https://price.metal.com/Rare-Earth (rare earth material prices) with Python/BeautifulSoup. The question is not about Python, but the HTML source code of the website. When I am using the "Inspect Element" function of Firefox I am getting the needed data/HTML tag I am looking for:

```
<div class="td-border-item frame-text-over-flow" title="294,000 ~ 299,000"> 294,000 ~ 299,000
```

But the problem is that when I view the Page Source of https://price.metal.com/Rare-Earth I cannot find the above element with

So I am curious if there is another HTML file which contains the information that I am looking for?

Comment: Yes. There are AJAX calls to  `https://price.metal.com/api/get_product_lists?t=1582288095974&second_level_name=rare+earth` which has `"newest_price":{"Average":296500,"Highs":299000,"Low":294000,`

Comment: The data has likely been loaded and inserted via JavaScript. What resources actually get loaded, should be easy enough to figure out using your browser dev tools, network panel.

Answer (score 0):

This element does not contain the value because it was loaded by asynchronization mechanism (**Ajax appending HTML value after that page loaded or binding data for example**).

I suggest you combine it with **Selenium Python** parallelly, inspect the tag and get value by Selenium. You will get it.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/